# Join repeating sequence to results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have a table that has data like:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
Test5
```

And another table with data like:

```
Foo1
Foo2
Foo3
```

How can I join the latter with the former like:

```
Test1  Foo1
Test2  Foo2
Test3  Foo3
Test4  Foo1
Test5  Foo2
```

Essentially repeating the same sequence from the second table for all of the first table.

**EDIT:**
I also need the data in the second table to stay in that order (it's coming from a table variable), even if they are not naturally in order alphabetically.

So, if the second table looks like:

```
Foo2
Foo3
Foo1
```

The result should look like:

```
Test1  Foo2
Test2  Foo3
Test3  Foo1
Test4  Foo2
Test5  Foo3
```

**EDIT2:**
The data for the second table is coming from the following `TVF`. I'm splitting a string that looks like "Foo1,Foo2,Foo3". How would I add a sequence to the result of that split?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
( 
    @Data varchar(max),
    @Delimiter varchar(max)
) 
RETURNS @Tokens table
(
    Token varchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN

while (charindex(@Delimiter, @Data) > 0)
begin
    insert into @Tokens (Token)
    select
        ltrim(rtrim(substring(@Data,1,charindex(@Delimiter,@Data)-1)))
    select
        @Data = substring(
                 @Data,charindex(@Delimiter,@Data)+len(@Delimiter),len(@Data))
end

insert into @Tokens (Token)
select
    ltrim(rtrim(@Data))

return
```

Comment: How are you ordering the data in the second table?, you need to add at least another column for that. Theres is no **natural order** on a table

Comment: You're right. See my 2nd edit for more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @T1 table(Col varchar(10))
declare @T2 table(Col varchar(10))

insert into @T1 values
('food1'),('food2'),('food3'),('food4'),('food5')

insert into @T2 values
('eat1'),('eat2'),('eat3')

;with C1 as
(
  select col,
         row_number() over(order by col) - 1 as rn
  from @T1
),
C2 as
(
  select col,
         row_number() over(order by col) - 1 as rn
  from @T2
)
select C1.col,
       C2.Col
from C1
  inner join C2
    on (C1.rn % (select count(*) from C2)) = C2.rn
order by C1.Col
```

**Update**

To get a sequence from your split function you can add a identity field in the returned table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
( 
    @Data varchar(max),
    @Delimiter varchar(max)
) 
RETURNS @Tokens table
(
    Token varchar(max),
    ID int identity
)
AS
BEGIN
 ....
```

Comment: This appears to do exactly what I want. I just have a question so I can better understand this solution. What is the purpose of the -1 on the C1 cte?

Comment: @JeremyCantrell - `row_number()` starts counting at 1 so I need that to get the modulus `%` to be correct. Without -1 on C1 you would have `eat2` as a match on `food1`. Plain wrong if you ask me :).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I have one caveat that I'm about to add to the question. If you can respond to that, I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @JeremyCantrell - Add a identity field in the returned table. I have updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really great answer and it furthered my understanding of CTE's.